# Building Darknet: Installing OpenCV for CUDA

Tags: opencv, yolo, darknet, yolov4

I'm having trouble building Darknet with the configuration:

```
GPU=1
CUDNN=1
CUDNN_HALF=0
OPENCV=1
```

The error when running the Makefile is:

```
/usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/stitching/detail/warpers.hpp:47:10: fatal error: opencv2/core/cuda.hpp: No such file or directory    47 |
#include "opencv2/core/cuda.hpp"
```

I have installed `cuda-11.2` and `cudann` successfully, and verified the installations.

I have tried running `sudo apt install libopencv-dev` and this was up-to-date.

My setup is:

```
os: Ubuntu 20.04
cuda version: 11.2
cudann version: 8.1
```

Can anyone help me install OpenCV such that I can build darknet with OpenCV?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the issue by running:

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove libopencv-dev
```

which purged the package, along with any dependencies required for the package. I then reinstalled the package by running:

```
sudo apt install libopencv-dev
```

and Darknet then built without error.

Comment: You look like installed opencv without cuda flag then